# Using @Qualifier still I am getting UnsatisfiedDependency Exception, can anybody help me with this

Tags: java, spring

```
public class Car {
    @Qualifier("e2")
    @Autowired  
    private Engine engine;

    public void printData() {
        System.out.println("Engine object ref "+engine.getModelOfYear());
        }
}

public class Engine {

    private String modelOfYear;

    public String getModelOfYear() {
        return modelOfYear;
    }
    public void setModelOfYear(String modelOfYear) {
        this.modelOfYear = modelOfYear;
    }
}
```

Spring.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
<beans>
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
    <bean id="e1" class="beans.Engine">
        <property name="modelOfYear" value="2013"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="e2" class="beans.Engine">
        <property name="modelOfYear" value="2011"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="c1" class="beans.Car"/>
</beans>
```

Test class

```
 public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ApplicationContext ap=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/Spring.xml");
            Car c=(Car)ap.getBean("c1");
            c.printData();
        }
    }
```

Exceptions I always getting

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'beans.Engine' available: expected single
>   matching bean but found 2: e1,e2
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveNotUnique(DependencyDescriptor.java:215)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
>         ... 15 more

Comment: Is there a reason you're using obsolete configuration?

Comment: @chrylis..Actually I was wondering why instantiation was not done through Qualifier by referring e2 or e1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Spring to process the `@Autowired` annotations in your XML declared beans, add `<context:annotation-config/>` to `Spring.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="e1" class="beans.Engine">
        <property name="modelOfYear" value="2013"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="e2" class="beans.Engine">
        <property name="modelOfYear" value="2011"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="c1" class="beans.Car"/>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing annotation with xml configuration.

You declare your bean `Car` in XML but `@Qualifier` it by annotation so it does not work.

Replace

```
<bean id="c1" class="beans.Car"/>
```

With:

```
<bean id="c1" class="beans.Car">
      <property name="engine" ref="e2"/>
</bean>
```

Or completely remove the xml configuration and using entirely annotation (which is preferred and recommended now)

Comment: Java and XML configuration are not exclusive - both can be used inside the same Spring application. https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0-m2/reference/html/mixing-configurations.html

Comment: @Manh your answer is not clear to me, I do not wanted to push e2 or e1 in spring.xml..please let me how can I do instantiation  through Qualifier

Comment: Post your xml after modification like my suggestion please

Comment: <bean id="c1" class="beans.Car">
  <property name="engine" ref="e2"/>
 </bean> this combination will work I know but my question is how I will only by @Qualifier

Comment: If you want to use `@Qualifier` only then remove the `<bean id = "c1"...` in your xml. Then add `@Component` to your `public class Car`

Comment: Does it help you?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'c1' available

Comment: Forgot to mention that your bean now named `car`. If you want to customize it name, add `@Bean(name = "c1")` above that `@Component`